# Vue Accordion: Override SCSS value

Tags: vue.js, sass, accordion

I'm using this accordion on my vue project: https://github.com/tkhquang/vue-simple-accordion#html-structure

I'm having trouble overriding the style on the button. The class name is "vsa-item__trigger" but I can't figure out a way to attach my style to it. The scss is in a style tag within my component. This is what my code looks like now:

```
            <vsa-list>
              <vsa-item  v-for="item in listOfItems" :key="item.id">
                <vsa-heading>
                  <label for="acc1 acc-label">  {{ item.heading }} </label>
                </vsa-heading>
                <vsa-content>
                  <ul class="mobile-ul-accordian">
                    <li class="mobile-li-accordian">
                      <a :href="item.url">{{ item.content }}</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>               
              </vsa-content>
              </vsa-item>
            </vsa-list>
```

```
button.vsa-item__trigger[type="button"][aria-expanded="false"] [data-vsa-list="14"] [data-vsa-item="15"] [data-vsa-active="false"] [aria-controls="vsa-panel-15"]{
  border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Try removing the `button.` in the start.

Comment: please show us how are you adding your style to component.

Comment: @michellesokolov Please let me know if my answer helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I just simplyfied your selector and this worked for me. Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Fabalance/4oaknpLd/3/).

```js
<button
        class="vsa-item__trigger"
        type="button"
        aria-expanded="true"
        aria-controls="vsa-panel-{item_id}"
        {data_attrs}
      >
        <span
          class="vsa-item__trigger__content"
          {data_attrs}
        >
          This is the heading
        </span>
        <span
          class="vsa-item__trigger__icon vsa-item__trigger__icon--is-active"
          {data_attrs}
        >
        </span>
      </button>
```

```css
button.vsa-item__trigger {
  border: none !important;
}
```